# [SQUID-6.1]: Setup Squid ipv4 to ipv6 proxy

Tags: proxy, ipv6, squid

I'm trying to setup a squid proxy that will accept multiple inbound connections on one IPv4 across a range of ports, and for each port connection to connect out on a unique IPv6 address.

I can actually connect to proxy but when I check my IP on a browser it says
the IPv4 address of the server.

Please help me to understand the issue

There is my **squid.conf** (ubuntu 22)

```
access_log none
cache_store_log none
cache deny all

forwarded_for delete
via off
follow_x_forwarded_for allow localhost
follow_x_forwarded_for deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access All deny all


acl to_ipv6 dst ipv6
http_access deny all !to_ipv6

acl allow_net src 1.1.1.1
http_access allow allow_net

# Common settings
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 21 # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https
acl Safe_ports port 70 # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210 # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280 # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488 # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591 # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777 # multiling http

http_access deny !Safe_ports

acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

auth_param basic program /usr/local/squid/libexec/basic_ncsa_auth /usr/local/squid/etc/squid.auth

auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Web-Proxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 1 minute
auth_param basic casesensitive off

acl db-auth proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow db-auth
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

coredump_dir /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid
unique_hostname V6proxies-Net
visible_hostname V6proxies-Net

http_port 10000
acl p10000 localport 10000
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:xxxx:f0:90e4:0098:0b13:xxxx:xxxx p10000

#http_port 10001
#acl p10001 localport 10001
#tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:xxxx:f0:b04b:3079:c399:xxxx:xxxx p10001
```

**network**

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 96:00:02:62:37:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet x.xxx.49.57/32 metric 100 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 83277sec preferred_lft 83277sec
    inet6 2a01:xxxx:f0:90e4:98:b13:6867:4e2a/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:xxxx:f0:90e4::1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:2ff:fe62:374c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```